# Simular barra de progreso

Tags: php, javascript, progressbar

Tengo una función en PHP que calcula el monto que debe pagar cada socio y a continuación le envía un email. En la Base de Datos hay como 4000 usuarios y me gustaría saber cuánto le queda al proceso.

Así que quiero hacer una barra de progreso en HTML que se irá actualizando conforme vaya enviando emails.

La idea que tuve fue que, al iniciar el proceso de enviar emails, creara una variable de sesión con la cantidad total de emails que tenia que enviar y la cantidad de emails que se enviaron. Y, acto seguido, en jJavaScript crear un setInterval que cada 1 segundo envié un AJAX asíncrono que recupere los datos de la variable de sesión.

Pero al intentar esta idea me devuelve todas las peticiones después de terminar el proceso, osea: si el proceso tardo 5 segundos, me devolverá cuanto termine el proceso 5 respuestas con el valor de 100%. También explore la variable XHR de AJAX, pero sólo localicé para la subida o descarga de archivos.

Me gustaría saber si alguien tiene ideas o ha logrado simular una barra de progreso.

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

otra idea si no quieres usar lo que comenta Xerif, es crear un archivo temporal y actualizarlo con los envios que vayas haciendo, y obviamente leerlo cada 2 segundos desde otra ventana  con jquery para mostrar el progreso.

Comment: Me gusto mucho tu idea y la lleve a cabo. Me funciono correctamente ademas de que así dejo un log por si ocurrió algo mal. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esto puede ser viable si el archivo no es procesado por php, por que cualquier petición del usuario que deba ser procesada por php quedará encolada a la espera de finalizar el Script anterior, si es lo que se desea bien. Pero si queremos que el usuario pueda seguir visitando otras páginas php esto no funcionará.

Answer (score 0):

Debes lanzar el Script en segundo plano para que apache y php creen otro hilo de ejecución y así no afecte a tu hilo principal.  Te puedes ayudar de la función **system( )**.

```
$orden = system( "php script_a_ejecutar.php");
```

Documentación:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.system.php

Sí en algún momento el comando a ejecutar con system va a recibir datos del usuario o de alguna fuente externa, deberías extremar la precaución y validar los datos concienzudamente además de escaparlos con las funciones proporcionadas por php para ello ya que de no hacerlo podría ser una gran amenaza para el entorno del servidor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, pero tu idea me resulto algo confusa y tome la de Borja J. Igualmente creo que funcionaría bien.

Comment: Siento que no hayas entendido totalmente mi respuesta. Pero con la respuesta de Borja tal y como está planteada te encontrás con el mismo problema que tenias, si necesitas ejecutar cualquier archivo php mientras la petición este en curso.